# Slow pywinauto Import

Tags: automation, pywinauto

When I import all most any module, it loads almost/seemingly instantly or at least fast enough to be unnoticeable.

However, there is an issue with PyWinAuto. When i try to import it, it takes a huge amount of time (~1min) which is highly annoying for the users.

I am wondering if there is anyway to be able to speed up the time it takes to load up the module.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `backend='uia'` it looks impossible, because `import comtypes` and loading `UIAutomationCore.dll` should take the most time and it's functionally required.

But if you need only default `backend='win32'` (i.e. if you create `Application()` object without `backend` parameter), you can run `pip uninstall -y comtypes`. Only Win32 backend will be available after that. But the import should work much faster.

More details about these 2 backends could be found in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: hmm, thank you, but im pretty sure that i do use comtypes in some other program. Would it somehow be possible just to make it not import comtypes without uninstalling it? thanks

Comment: I can think about fixing it in next pywinauto release. But I have no appropriate slow system to reproduce it on my side. First I need to make sure that not importing comtypes does the trick. Can you uninstall comtypes, check import time and then install comtypes again?